# Filtered query as model and controller for named outlet

Tags: ember.js

I have a fantasy sports app with Player and Team models.  I'm trying to output a query on the Players model/fixture as a model iterated by a template in a named outlet.  I think my problem is with the 'availableTeams' controller/route/model/route.

I'm trying to do a find on my Player model for players that don't have a team.

```
App.AvailablePlayersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
 availPlayers: function() {
    return App.Player.find({league: ''});
    // return App.Player.find({league: 'mlb'}); // Doesn't work either
  },
});
```

The template is rendering because the static text shows up, but the Chrome emberjs debugger shows the model of availablePlayers as having no value.  I've searched SO, the EmberJS.com getting started guide and countless JSFiddles, but nothings working.  I don't know if my approach is wrong, or if I'm missing something simple.  Any help is appreciated.

Full JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/sandalsoft/77P8z/

PS - The app is a multiple-sport fantasy league where teams are the players, so don't let the team names in the Player fixture throw you.

**EDIT: Updated the fiddle which now runs: http://jsfiddle.net/77P8z/**

Comment: could you fix your jsfiddle? it has relative path's for the javascript files you are referencing

Comment: Ugh, sorry. Updated here: http://jsfiddle.net/77P8z/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `renderTemplate` your controller does not get a model from the route, since there is no route. The finder you used is returning a `promise`, but this stuff belongs in the route. It's a Catch-22, so you have to manually set the `content` or `model` on the controller.

I typically do this just before the custom `render`. You could do it it elsewhere, the key is to set the content manually. Here's the modified `renderTemplate` of `ApplicationRoute`,

```
var availController = this.controllerFor('availablePlayers');
App.Player.find({league: 'epl'}).then(function(result) {
    availController.set('model', result);
});

// render into outlet
```

The updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BzNW2/1/).

I noticed you are using rc.3. Try switching to rc.6 if possible, you will need the async router, and the bug fixes in it eventually.

Comment: Works great, thank you!  One question though, this functionality seems better suited for the AvaialblePlayersRouter.  Why won't 'model: function() {[code above]}' work there?  I tried setting the model: explicitly a few different ways in the AvailablePlayersRouter and and none of them worked, why?

Comment: because you aren't on the `AvailablePlayersRoute` but on the `ApplicationRoute`. when rendering with `renderTemplate`. Hence the extra work.